# jqgrid aftersavefunc not firing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.8 JavaScript, I'm using inline edit and clientArray. 
Now, I want to change value in a cell and save row, so the code is:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'comments', 'test');
var saveparameters = {
    "successfunc": null,
    "url": 'clientArray',
    "aftersavefunc": function (rowid, response, options) {
        alert('b');
    },
    "extraparam": {},
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc": null,
    "restoreAfterError": true,
    "mtype": "POST"
};
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', rowId, saveparameters);
```

...but the alert never fires. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you! I modified my code and finally it became to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will only fire if you call:

```
 $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('editRow', rowId, false);
```

Reference:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow